# Como capturar o HttpEntity em um HttpResponse mais de uma vez?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

No meu projeto, criei uma classe Helper chamada HttpResponseHelper para obter o corpo do meu HttpResponse.

No entanto, ao executar o comando `HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity()` ele só retorna na primeira chamada, após a segunda, recebo um erro.

Veja meu código:

```
public static String getResponseBody(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    if (httpResponse != null) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        return EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de eu usar `EntityUtils.toString()` para obter o `HttpEntity` mais de uma vez?

Existe uma maneira de fazer o que eu quero fazer sem usar `EntityUtils.toString()`, por exemplo usando o Interceptor do Spring?

Se houver alguma maneira de armazenar esse valor em String como se estivesse armazenado em cache, seria uma boa ideia também.

Comment: Salvar o httpEntity em uma variavel de backup não resolveria seu problema?

Comment: Erick, Obrigado pela resposta ! O problema é que eu espero usar o responseBody em várias classes e não apenas em uma classe especifica. Guardar ela em uma váriavel especifica, eu teria que ficar passando ela pelo meu codigo inteiro em vez de fazer apenas ```EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) ```.

Comment: Experimenta tornar essa variável de backup estática e não o método getResponseBody();